# Open file share DOCX files using Office Online Server

Tags: sharepoint-search, office-online-server

We heavily use SharePoint 2019 to crawl our on-premise **file shares**.

The search results from SharePoint 2019 return files with a "file://" protocol in the URL. Microsoft Edge has a GPO that allows us to unblock these links so that, when clicked, Windows opens a Windows Explorer with the file preselected.

This is a somewhat acceptable workaround, but what I really want to know is if it is possible to have the file open in OOO (office online server). Has anyone been able to get this working?